# Should i use delete[] in a function?

Tags: c++

```
void work() {
  int *p;
  p=new int[10];
  //some code....
}
```

I have a short question that in the **work** function, should i use delete[] operator? since when **work** function is over, **p** will be destroyed, which is wrong or right ? (My English is bad, i am sorry).

Comment: There are a lot of disadvantages in using `new[]` and `delete[]`; with potential memory leaks being only one of them.    You should avoid using them and prefer `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work as long as the code throws no exceptions...

```
void work() {
    int *p;
    p=new int[10];
    //some code....
    delete [] p;
}
```

This is better (but difficult to maintain):

```
void work1() {
    int *p;
    p=new int[10];
    try {
    //some code....
    } catch(...) {
        delete [] p;
    }
    delete [] p;
}
```

This is much better...

```
void work2()
{
    auto p = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[10]);
    // some code...

    // memory is automatically deleted
}
```

And this is how you should do it...

```
void work3()
{
    auto v = std::vector<int>(10);
    // some code...
}
```

Comment: I'm a beginer, that is my first question, thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

You're right, if you have no reference to `p` outside of the function, e.g. a global variable, then you need to call `delete [] p` right inside of the function, otherwise the reference to the allocated memory you want to free is lost.

Comment: A call to `new []` must be matched with a corresponding call to `delete []`.   Omitting the brackets is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I omitted the brackets because I wasn't writing actual code, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if integers are allocated using `new int[10]`, you need to clean up using `delete[]`, since it is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to release the memory from new.

Alternatively with C++11, you can use smart pointer:

```
void work() {
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> p{ new int[10] };
  //some code....
  // RAII will delete[] magically here
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using just few integers (10 in your case), that are known in compile time, you can do "normal" or `static` array. e.g.

```
void work() {
  /* static */ int p[10];
  //some code....
}
```

Alternatively, use `std::vector`:

```
void work() {
  std::vector<int> p{10};
  //some code....
  // RAII will delete[] magically here
}
```

Alternatively, with `C++11` if array size is known in compile time, use `std::array`:

```
void work() {
  std::array<int,10> p;
  //some code....
  // RAII will delete[] magically here
}
```

Comment: If you want to use a fixed number of integers known at compile time, that is.

Comment: If this is your first code, use `std::vector`. if this is code for school, use `delete[]`, because in schools they teach you `C with classes` and for good or bad, they want to see you can manage the memory yourself, as it would be done in `C`.